# Remodal option closeOnEscape does not work with multiple controls on a page

Tags: jquery

When using [Remodal](https://github.com/VodkaBears/Remodal), when I add two controls on a page, the "closeOnEscape" option no longer works. For example, with two different divs on a page to be shown by two different clicks on the page, they are defined as:

```
<div class="remodal appointmentSlotEditor calendarPageDialog" data-remodal-id="editAppointmentSlotModal">
```

And

```
<div class="remodal task-details" data-remodal-id="modal-task-details">
```

They both show fine, and closeOnAnyClick works well, but when trying to assign the option closeOnEscape (in any way), it no longer works. When following the code through the jquery.remodal.js file, this function executes as many times as there are modals on the page - I think this is the problem. Any thoughts?

```
// Add the keyboard event listener
$(document).on('keyup.' + namespace, function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 27 && remodal.settings.closeOnEscape) {
    remodal.close();
  }
});
```

Is there a way to change the namespace, or filter the listener to let that option work for just one popup?

Thanks,
James